# How to loop two DateTime by minutes? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, date, datetime

var start = "13.04.2019 10:00:00";
var end = "14.04.2019 16:00:00";

I need to loop minute by minute. please help me.

```
// var start = "13.04.2019 10:00:00";
// var end = "14.04.2019 16:00:00";

var start = new Date(2019,05,13,11,00,00,00);
var end = new Date(2019,05,14,16,00,00,00);

var loop = start;
while(loop <= end){
   console.log(loop);

   var loop = loop.setTime(loop.getMinutes() + 1);
}
```

not working :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setMinutes` instead of `setTime` You can modify your code to this and everything will work,

```
var start = new Date(2019,05,13,11,00,00,00);
var end = new Date(2019,05,14,16,00,00,00);
var loop = start;
while(loop <= end){
    loop.setMinutes(loop.getMinutes() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change to this

```
loop = loop.setTime(loop.getMinutes() + 1);
```

it will change type of loop to number and cant call `getMinutes()`

```js
var start = new Date(2019,05,13,11,00,00,00);
var end = new Date(2019,05,14,16,00,00,00);

var loop = start;
while(loop <= end){
   console.log(loop);

   loop.setTime(loop.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use moment library for date operations

```
    var start = moment('13-04-2019 10:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
    var end = moment('14-04-2019 16:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');

    var diffInMinutes = end.diff(start,'minutes');
    var res=moment('13-04-2019 10:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');

    for(let i=0;i<diffInMinutes;i++){
       console.log(res.add(1,'minutes'));
    }
```

sample output

```
   13-04-2019 10:01
   13-04-2019 10:02
   13-04-2019 10:03
   13-04-2019 10:04
   13-04-2019 10:05
```